# how to manually open and close the popup using Magnific-Popup

Tags: magnific-popup

In jquery dialogs we can do

```
$("#id").dialog('open|close')
```

to open close dialogs. how to do this in Magnific-popup?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

```
$.magnificPopup.open({
  items: {
    src: '#id'
  },
  type: 'inline'
});
```

http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/magnific-popup/documentation.html#public_methods

Comment: Didn't work for me for youtube links with iframe.

Comment: Thanks this works GREAT, crazy this wasnt well documented on their website